# Visualize a tree structure using TreeGraph

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks, visualization, data-structures, conversion

I have a code that generates a tree of graphics objects. The structure can be visualized like this, with each `Rule` constituting a parent child relationship:

```
children[list_] := ReplaceList[list, {a___, x_, b___} :> Rule[x, children[{a, b}]]]
children[{a, b, c}] // TreeForm
```

[image: tree]

A better way of visualizing the result I want, courtesy of Halirutan is this:

```
children[list_] :=  ReplaceList[list, {a___, x_, b___} :> (x @@ children[{a, b}])]
children[{a, b, c}] // TreeForm
```

[image: result example 2]

However my real code like I said has graphics in it. So each symbol in the above image is a graphics object. An example of this:

```
r[col_] := Graphics[{col, Rectangle[]}]
treeData = children[{r[Red], r[Green], r[Blue]}];
```

I would like to visualize this tree using `TreeGraph` where each `VertexShape` is the corresponding graphics object. So for the leftmost branch I expect graphics object `a` and from it two arrows one two graphics object `b` and one to graphics object `c` and so on. Example of expected output from `children[{r[Red],r[Blue]}] // renderTree`:

```
TreeGraph[{
  DirectedEdge[1, 2],
  DirectedEdge[1, 3],
  DirectedEdge[2, 4],
  DirectedEdge[3, 5]
  }, VertexShape -> {
   2 -> r[Red],
   3 -> r[Blue],
   4 -> r[Blue],
   5 -> r[Red]
   }, VertexSize -> 0.5]
```

[image: example tree]

Speed is not important since I will only be doing this on relatively small trees for visualization purposes. I can change the code that generates the tree data so you are free to do that as well, you don't have to work with the data as it is. You might want to insert custom heads for example. That is one approach I've tried. However I don't have any code to share, I hope that will not cause a riot. But if it does I shall accept it stoically I hope, I know how important showing an effort is to some of you. I don't know what a good start is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me give you an outline. First and as discussed in chat I change your tree data-structure a bit to make it smaller. A tree with a root `r` and two children `a` and `b` is now represented as `r[a,b]` which is a natural representation in *Mathematica*. To create a tree like you showed I use a function `Node` which does the job.

```
Node[root_, {args__}] := root[Sequence @@ 
    ReplaceList[{args}, {start___, elm_, end___} :> Node[elm, {start, end}]]];
Node[root_, {}] := root

Node[root, {r, g, b}] // TreeForm
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

The tree in pure input form can be given by

> ```
> root[r[g[b], b[g]], g[r[b], b[r]], b[r[g], g[r]]]
> ```

To transform this into a representation suitable for `TreeGraph` it is probably best if you familiarise yourself with how to traverse a tree. One easy method is the following which will later be used and is now given as toy-function which traverses the tree and just prints the nodes it sees:

```
test[h_[childs__]] := (Print[h]; test /@ {childs});
test[leaf_] := Print[leaf]

test[Node[root, {r, g, b}]];
```

As output you see how the nodes are visited in pre-order (or depth-first). The rest is quite easy. On every visit you have knowledge about the node and its children so you just have to label the nodes with a unique `id` (I called it `counter`) and then you create the `DirectedEdge` and the *rendered shape rule* you need. This all happens in the `traverse` function. Then only the result list needs to be restructured to fit into `TreeGraph`

```
makeTree[nodes_, renderFunc_] := Module[{counter = 0},
  traverse[h_[childs___]] := With[{id = counter},
    {DirectedEdge[id, ++counter], counter -> renderFunc[#], 
       traverse[#]} & /@ {childs}];
  traverse[_] := Sequence[];

  TreeGraph[#1, VertexShape -> #2] & @@ 
   Transpose[Partition[Flatten[traverse[nodes]], 2]]
]
```

Finally, we need the `renderFunc`. Since all our nodes and leafs look like `r[...]` or `r` respectively, a simple implementation is straight forward

```
render[r[___] | r] := Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[]}];
render[b[___] | b] := Graphics[{Blue, Rectangle[]}];
render[g[___] | g] := Graphics[{Green, Rectangle[]}];
```

Et voila

```
makeTree[Node[root, {r, g, b}], render]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Very nice, thank you.