# Can trees be made into graphs?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, trees

When one has the output of a function like TreeForm, for instance:

[image]

Can this be turned into a `Graph` object? I would like to be able to apply functions like `VertexList`, `VertexDegree`, `AdjacencyList`, and so on.

Comment: See my [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/116666/how-can-i-re-create-the-original-graph-object-from-graphics-object-into-which-th)

Comment: I am attempting to use the answer from Wjx, but I am running into a problem. I cannot apply the function Graphics2Graph directly to TreeForm, only to the output of TreeForm. For example, Graphics2Graph[TreeForm[{{a, a}, {a, {a, a}}}]] does not work. I would also be happy with a method to take such a list and make the corresponding graph.

Comment: See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/151159/21532)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use halirutan's `makeTree` function from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/42299/731). Your purpose is slightly different than the purpose in that question, so the function can be simplified a bit in this context:

```
makeTree[nodes_] := Module[{counter = 0},
  traverse[h_[childs___]] := With[{id = counter},
    {DirectedEdge[id, ++counter], traverse[#]} & /@ {childs}
    ];
  traverse[_] := Sequence[];
  TreeGraph[#, GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding"] &@Flatten[traverse[nodes]]
  ]
```

Use it like this:

```
expr = TreeForm[{a, {a, {a, a, a}}}];
{expr, makeTree @@ expr}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This method will lose all vertices information

Comment: @yode You can use this `Graph` object with `VertexDegree`, `AdjacancyList` etc. I do not store the the labels (`List`,  `a`), but it could be added. Other than that I don't lose any information.

Answer (score 5):

```
TreeFormToGraph[treeForm_] := 
 Module[{tree = ToExpression@ToBoxes@treeForm, order, pos, label},
  label = Cases[tree, Inset[name_, n_] :> Rule[n, Placed[name, Center]],Infinity];
  {order, pos} = Catenate /@ Cases[tree, 
     Line[order_] | GraphicsComplex[pos_, ___] :> {order, pos}, Infinity];
  Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ order, VertexLabels -> label, 
   VertexCoordinates -> MapIndexed[Rule[First[#2], #] &, pos]]]
```

Note the result of `TreeFormToGraph` is `Graph` object.

### Example 1:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Example 2:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** We can use `` GraphComputation`ExpressionGraph `` to get a one-liner that converts a `TreeForm` object to a `Graph` object:

```
treeFormToGraph = Apply[GraphComputation`ExpressionGraph];

treeFormToGraph @ TreeForm[{{{a,b},c},d}]
```

[image]

We can add styling to get a `Graph` that looks like `TreeForm`:

```
ClearAll[treeFormToGraph ]
treeFormToGraph[t_TreeForm, o : OptionsPattern[]] := 
   Module[{g = GraphComputation`ExpressionGraph[t[[1]], o, 
           VertexSize -> {"Scaled", .1}, VertexStyle -> LightYellow, 
           VertexShapeFunction -> "Rectangle"]}, 
      SetProperty[g, VertexLabels -> (PropertyValue[g, VertexLabels] /. 
              Rule[a_, b_] :> Rule[a, Placed[b, Center]])]];

treeFormToGraph[TreeForm[{{{a,b},c},d}], VertexStyle->Pink]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

We can use, instead of `TreeForm`, `` GraphComputation`ExpressionGraph `` which produces a `Graph` object accepting all the options of `Graph`.

```
g1 = GraphComputation`ExpressionGraph[{{{a, b}, c}, d}, 
   VertexSize -> {"Scaled", .1}, VertexStyle -> LightYellow, 
   VertexShapeFunction -> "Rectangle"];

SetProperty[g1, VertexLabels -> (PropertyValue[g1, VertexLabels] /. 
    Rule[a_, b_] :> Rule[a, Placed[b, Center]])]
```

[image]

Comment: As my understand,this topic is about how to convert a `Graphics` into `Graph`. :)

Comment: @yode, i assume you meant "_convert a `TreeForm` into `Graph`_". ``Apply[GraphComputation`ExpressionGraph]@TreeForm[{{{a,b}, c}, d}]`` does it:)

Comment: @kglr thank you for introducing me to this function! :)

Comment: @kglr: Is it possible to adjust the length of the arrows.

Comment: `AspectRatio -> 1/3`?

Answer (score 3):

This is not ideal. It requires the tree to be output. The object elements are collected and reused for a graph:

```
func[ex__] := (e = {}; vn = {};
  TreeForm[ex, 
   EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Blue, (AppendTo[e, #]; 
        Arrow[#, .3])} &), 
   VertexRenderingFunction -> ((AppendTo[vn, {#1, #2}]; 
       Text[#2, #1]) &)])
f[x_, y_] := 
 Module[{el = DeleteDuplicates[UndirectedEdge @@@ x], vl, rules},
  vl = VertexList[Graph[el]];
  rules = MapIndexed[#1 -> #2[[1]] &, vl];
  Graph[el /. rules, VertexLabels -> Rule @@@ (y /. rules)]]
```

An example:

```
func[{a, b, {c, d}, {w, r}}] (* tree must be rendered*)
graph = f[e, vn]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) now includes a function to convert a Mathematica expression into a `Graph` similar to what `TreeForm` would display. It is faster than `` GraphComputation`ExpressionGraph ``, especially if you turn off vertex labelling.

```
IGExpressionTree[{{{a, a}, a}, a}]
```

[image]

```
tree = IGExpressionTree[expr = {{{a, a}, a}, a}, VertexLabels -> None, 
 GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", "RootVertex" -> {}}]
```

[image]

The vertex names of this tree are the positions of the corresponding subexpressions. Above, the root vertex was set to `{}`, which is the [position specification](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html) of the entire expression.

```
VertexList[tree]
(* {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1}, {2}, {}} *)

Extract[expr, VertexList[tree]]
(* {a, a, {a, a}, a, {{a, a}, a}, a, {{{a, a}, a}, a}} *)
```

We could also have labelled the vertices with these subexpressions:

```
IGExpressionTree[expr, VertexLabels -> "Subexpression", 
 GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", "RootVertex" -> {}}]
```

[image]

Should you need the vertex names to be just integers, use [`IndexGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IndexGraph.html).

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR : I have provided some 2021 updates and "option-feature customizabilty" for the previous `ExpressionGraph` and `Graph` solutions -- see below for the code.

---

Half of my answer is a 2021 update to the [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/187607/76328) provided by [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs) and the [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/151208/76328) provided by [kglr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125/kglr).  It appears that the former `` GraphComputation`ExpressionGraph `` has now been migrated to vanilla `ExpressionGraph` (no `` GraphComputation` ``  context anymore).  The posted code which previously worked doesn't translate directly into the new function, but I have performed some minor tweaks to make it work in 2021.

In addition to 2021 compatibility, I have added two features.  The first feature is the ability to auto-size the `VertexLabel`s.  This includes auto-sizing the frame around the text, and setting a maximum font size, after which the text auto-shrinks.  The second feature is simply some syntactic sugar to wrap some code around `Graph` and allow arbitrary user-specified customizations. The customizations work in a manner similar to the existing `VertexLabelFunction` option, and custom functions have access to all the available underlying `Graph` data.

I have provided one version that works with `` GraphComputation`ExpressionGraph `` and another that works with vanilla `Graph`, which allows a plethora of customization (e.g. via the `GraphLayout` option).  See the reference manual pages for `Graph` and `GraphLayout` for further information.

EDIT: After re-reading the original post, I converted the code to use `Graph` directly instead of `TreePlot` (whose output *is* a `Graph` object, but the original post specifically requested the use of `Graph`).  See the edit history if you'd like a `TreePlot` version; it's literally three symbols of changes (`TreePlot` <--> `Graph` wherever they appear).

---

Now the code...

---

Vanilla 2021 `ExpressionGraph`

```
ExpressionGraph[
   #,
   VertexLabels -> Placed[Automatic, Center],
   VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> Scaled@0.04],
   VertexStyle -> LightYellow,
   VertexShapeFunction -> "Rectangle",
   VertexSize -> 3/4,
   ImageSize -> Large
   ] &@Power[Plus[a, b, c], Sqrt[c/d]]
```

---

New `SizedVertices` function
[Compatible with both `ExpressionGraph` and my new `ExprTreeGraph` below]

```
SizedVertices = Function[vertexLabels,
   Function[{center, vertex, size},
    With[
     {
      SizedInset = Inset[#, center, {Center, Center}, size*2] &,
      Styled = Style[#, FontSize -> 2*144*size[[2]]/4, Black] &,
      YellowFrame = 
       Framed[#, Background -> LightYellow, Alignment -> Center] &,
      ScaledPane = 
       Pane[#, ImageSize -> {UpTo@Full, UpTo@Full}, 
         Alignment -> Center, ImageSizeAction -> "ShrinkToFit"] &
      },
     SizedInset@
      Styled@YellowFrame@ScaledPane@ToString@vertexLabels[[vertex]]
     ]]];
```

Usage:

```
ExpressionGraph[
   #,
   VertexSize -> 3/4,
   VertexShapeFunction -> 
    SizedVertices@Cases[#, _, {-1}, Heads -> True],
   ImageSize -> Large
   ] &@Power[Plus[a, b, c], Sqrt[c/d]]
```

---

New `ExprTreeGraph` Function
[Based upon `Graph`, but with handy defaults and a new `OptionsFunction`]

```
ClearAll@ExprTreeGraph
With[{F = Function[f, Sequence[{v, e, lbl}, f] &, HoldAll]},
  Options[ExprTreeGraph] = {
    "VertexFunction" -> F@v,
    "EdgeFunction" -> F@Thread@Rule[e, Most@v],
    "OptionsFunction" -> F@Nothing,
    "VertexLabelFunction" -> 
     F@Thread@Rule[v, Thread@Placed[lbl, Center]],
    VertexShapeFunction -> "Rectangle",
    VertexSize -> 3/4,
    VertexStyle -> LightYellow,
    VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> Scaled@0.04],
    GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding"
    }];

ExprTreeGraph[expr_, o : OptionsPattern[{ExprTreeGraph, Graph}]] := 
 With[{
   parts = Position[expr, _, Heads -> False],
   LabelParents = 
    Flatten@Through@Thread[FirstPosition@Drop[#, -1, -1]]@# &,
   HandleAtomic = Replace[{} -> {1}],
   HeadIf = Replace[part_?(Not@*AtomQ) :> Head@part]
   },
  With[{v = Range@Length@parts,
    e = HandleAtomic@LabelParents@parts,
    lbl = Extract[expr, parts, HeadIf]
    },
   Graph[
    OptionValue["VertexFunction"][v, e, lbl],
    OptionValue["EdgeFunction"][v, e, lbl],
    Sequence @@ Normal@Merge[First]@(FilterRules[#, Options@Graph] &)@{
         OptionValue["OptionsFunction"][v, e, lbl],
         o,
         VertexLabels -> OptionValue["VertexLabelFunction"][v, e, lbl],
         Options@ExprTreeGraph
         }
    ]]]
```

Usage:

```
ExprTreeGraph@Power[Plus[a, b, c], Sqrt[c/d]]
```

Or:

```
ExprTreeGraph[
 Power[Plus[a, b, c], Sqrt[c/d]],
 ImageSize -> Large,
 VertexLabels -> None,
 OptionsFunction -> ((VertexShapeFunction -> SizedVertices[#3]) &)
 ]
```

Example output of auto-sizing function:

[image: LayeredDigraphEmbedding]