# How to assign the real result of *Form function to a variable?

Tags: graphics, output-formatting

Of course we know,the `TreeForm[a + b^2 + c^3 + d]` will give a `Graphics` object.How to assign to a variable an expression which typesets to the same box structure as a TreeForm of a particular input?

Maybe one think we just use the `var=TreeForm[a + b^2 + c^3 + d]`,but you will find the `Head` of the `var` is `TreeForm`.I record a gif for specify this case.

[image]

And I found this regular is apply to any `*Form` function.Such as `InputForm`

```
a = InputForm[Graphics[Circle[]]];
Head[a]
```

> `InputForm`

I have a awkward workaround calling the clipboard can do it almost.

```
var = NotebookGet[CopyToClipboard[TreeForm[a + b^2 + c^3 + d]]; 
  ClipboardNotebook[]]
```

But there are some problem in this solution.

1. `var` include all information,but the `Head` of `var` is not `Graphics` actually.
2. I really don't want to call the clipboard.

So how to assign the `Graphics` object to a variable?

Comment: Type `var=TreeForm[a+b^2+c^3+d]`, select the right hand side and press ctrl-shift-enter (that is evaluate in place) and evaluate the cell.

Comment: @FredSimons I know that,but that is not my after.Anyway thanks. :)

Answer (score 6):

We have to be careful with wording.

What you really want to do is to "assign to a variable an expression which typesets to the same box structure as a `TreeForm` of a particular input".

And this can be achieved with:

```
test = ToExpression @ ToBoxes @ TreeForm[a + b];
```

So once you know what you want the solution is obvious.

to confirm:

```
test // InputForm // SequenceForm
```

> ```
>    Graphics[Annotation[
>   GraphicsComplex[{{0.4472135954999579, 0.8944271909999159}, {0., 
>      0.}, {0.8944271909999159, 0.}}, {{RGBColor[0.55, 0.45, 0.45], 
>      Line[{{1, 2}, {1, 3}}]}, {Tooltip[
>       Inset[Framed[
>         Style[Plus, {"StandardForm", "Output", GrayLevel[0]}, 
>          FontSize -> Scaled[0.05]], 
>         Background -> RGBColor[1., 1., 0.871], 
>         FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[0.5], FrameMargins -> Inherited], 1], 
>       HoldForm[a + b]], 
>      Tooltip[Inset[
>        Framed[Style[
>          HoldForm[a], {"StandardForm", "Output", GrayLevel[0]}, 
>          FontSize -> Scaled[0.05]], 
>         Background -> RGBColor[1., 1., 0.871], 
>         FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[0.5], FrameMargins -> Inherited], 2], 
>       HoldForm[a]], 
>      Tooltip[Inset[
>        Framed[Style[
>          HoldForm[b], {"StandardForm", "Output", GrayLevel[0]}, 
>          FontSize -> Scaled[0.05]], 
>         Background -> RGBColor[1., 1., 0.871], 
>         FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[0.5], FrameMargins -> Inherited], 3], 
>       HoldForm[b]]}}, {}], 
>   VertexCoordinateRules -> {{0.4472135954999579, 
>      0.8944271909999159}, {0., 0.}, {0.8944271909999159, 0.}}], 
>  FrameTicks -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, 
>  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.1], AspectRatio -> 1, 
>  FormatType :> StandardForm]
> ```

Comment: To be honest, I cannot imagine `ToBoxes` can do such thing still..

Comment: @yode that is exactly what is expected from `ToBoxes`, the main problem here is to realize that we work here with typset/boxes representation not ordinary expressions. Which is expected as we deal here with *Forms.